# How to get the parent object in PHP, from OUTSIDE the object itself?

Tags: php, reflection, parent

I am using Reflections to adjust various values in objects, and I have an object who's parent I need to adjust.

For example:

```
class Ford extends Car
{
    private $model;
}

class Car
{
    private $color;
}
```

I can easily use Reflection to change the model, but how can I separate the parent from the child, so that I can use Reflection on the parent?

**Some psuedo code for what I'm hoping is possible:**

```
$ford = new Ford();

$manipulator = new Manipulator($ford);

$manipulator->set('model','F-150');
$manipulator->setParentValue('color','red');

class Manipulator
{
    public function __construct($class) {
        $this->class = $class;
        $this->reflection = new \ReflectionClass($class);
    }

    public function set($property,$value) {
        $property = $this->reflection->getProperty($property);
        $property->setAccessible(true);
        $property->setValue($this->class,$value);
    }

    public function setParentValue() {

        $parent = $this->reflection->getParent();

        $property = $this->reflection->getProperty($property);
        $property->setAccessible(true);

        // HOW DO I DO THIS?

        $property->setValue($this->class::parent,$value);
    }
}
```

**Gist of the question:**

In this case, how can I change the $color from outside the object altogether?

Is there something like Ford::parent() or get_parent_object($ford) available?

**Note**

The objects used above are not the exact scenario, but just used to illustrate the concept. In the real world case, I have a parent/child relationship, and I need to be able to access/change values in each from the outside.

**ANSWER**

Please check my answer below...I figured it out.

Comment: Car should have the $model property.. it just can't access it since it's private. If you use reflection on Car and try to get the $model property does it give you an error?

Comment: I haven't tried. I will try, but that's almost irrelevant in this situation, I think. The objects used above are not the exact scenario, but just used to illustrate the concept. In the real world case, I have a parent/child relationship, and I need to be able to access/change values in each from the outside.

Comment: There is no such relationship for properties in PHP. You can access parent methods using `parent::myMethod()` but you don't see that for properties because they all exist on the same plain.. only their scope and accessibility changes. I might be interpreting this question entirely wrong.. it might help if you included the (psuedo) reflection code you're trying to apply in the Car/Ford example

Comment: For sure, but that's what I am using Reflection...you can setValues($entity). If I can do that, it stands to reason that somehow I could setValues($entity::parent) ... no?

Comment: @MikeB just added some psuedo code :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After extensive review, I have found that I can't access the parent of an object AS AN OBJECT outside of the object itself.

However, using Reflections, I was able to solve the example posted above:

```
    <?php
class Car
{
    private $color;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->color = 'red';
    }

    public function color()
    {
        return $this->color;
    }
}

class Ford extends Car
{
}

$ford = new Ford();

echo $ford->color(); // OUTPUTS 'red'

$reflection = new ReflectionClass($ford);

$properties = $reflection->getProperties();
foreach($properties as $property) {
    echo $property->getName()."\n>";
}

$parent = $reflection->getParentClass();

$color = $parent->getProperty('color');
$color->setAccessible(true);
$color->setValue($ford,'blue');

echo $ford->color(); // OUTPUTS 'blue'
```

See it in action here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/R45LN0

Answer (score 1):

See get_parent_class(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-parent-class.php

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that...but doesn't that just get the name of the parent class? How can I leverage that to change the color of the car in the example above? Thanks!

Comment: It's a private property, sou you should not access it directly. Use getter/setter methods, such as

class Car {
 private $color:
 public function getColor() { return $this->color; }
 public function setColor($newcolor) { $this->color = $newcolor; }
}

Comment: Typically that would work, but in this specific case, I need to be able to change values from the outside, without changing the child class in any way. That's why I've been using Reflection so far.

Comment: So you can't change either class?

Comment: Correct. They exist completely separately of this function. The real scenario is I have a Car, and dynamically created a class that extends Car w/o it's knowledge to allow for things like lazy-loading of Car, etc. It's based on how Doctrine2 handles Proxies.

Comment: What about creating a child class for Ford with a single method kinda like `getGrandParent() { return parent::parent; }`? It's awful, but it seems to fit your constraints.

Comment: That's a good start, I think. But, I believe it only get's the ReflectionClass for the parent. I still would need a reference to the actual parent to set the values of the parent with $childReflection->getParentClass()->getProperty('color')->setValue($ford,'red'); Right?

Answer (score 1):

```
function getPrivateProperty(\ReflectionClass $class, $property)
{
    if ($class->hasProperty($property)) {
        return $class->getProperty($property);
    }

    if ($parent = $class->getParentClass()) {
        return getPrivateProperty($parent, $property);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation [really helps](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the static version of the function I [answered your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30878285/904344) with:

```
function getProperties($object) {
    $properties = array();
    try {
        $rc = new \ReflectionClass($object);
        do {
            $rp = array();
            /* @var $p \ReflectionProperty */
            foreach ($rc->getProperties() as $p) {
                $p->setAccessible(true);
                $rp[$p->getName()] = $p->getValue($object);
            }
            $properties = array_merge($rp, $properties);
        } while ($rc = $rc->getParentClass());
    } catch (\ReflectionException $e) { }
    return $properties;
}
```